# Autolayout for UIImageView in storyboard without image

Tags: uiimageview, autolayout, storyboard

I have an UIImageView in storyboard that has no image set.  I don't want the width to be set at design time, but rather have the image assigned to it at runtime drive the intrinsic content size but storyboard gives me a constraint error on missing constraint.  What should I do to get rid of that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a width constraint to the `UIImageView` and then in the *Size inspector*, click the box next to **Placeholder Remove at build time**:

[image: Placeholder constraint]

This *Placeholder constraint* will satisfy *Interface Builder*, but it will be removed at build time and not get in the way at runtime.